# Multithread app not working on windows 7

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-7-x64

Im am trying to make an Windows Form App. The app uses multithreading and each thread calls a methos and it updates controls created on the main thread. I use invoke to update the controls and the app works on Windows server enterprise but it doesent on Windows 7 64 bit. On WIndows 7 the application stops doing anything after updating the interface 2 times. I don't know what seems to be the problem. I tried with multiple threads and with task(`Task.Factory.StartNew()`) and i had the same result(updates the control 2 times). No error message. 
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
In `CallMethod()` i'm calling a WCF and waiting for respont. It seems that WCF call is returning something for the first two threads and for the rest it's not...

code:

Main method:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < NoThreads; i++)
            {
                int index = i;
                Thread t = new Thread(CallMethod);
                t.Name = "Thread [" + Cicle + "] Cicle [" + i + "]";
                threads[i] = t;

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < NoThreads; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Start();
            }
```

CallMethod:

```
private string CallMethod()
{
 try
   {
      //calling a webservice

      string message = .....
      if (txtResult.InvokeRequired)
      { txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => txtResult.AppendText(message))); }
 catch
 {throw;}

}
```

Comment: Supposing txtResult.InvokeRequired is false... Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, make sure all paths through CallMethod() update the UI (even if it's just with a "got to this point" text). It seems like txtResult.InvokeRequired may be false, or perhaps you are getting an exception from the web request.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**
I had to close the connection after calling the WCF in each thread

Answer (score -1):

A sample of working on x64 machine (Windows 7) for thread:

```
class Server
{
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private Thread listenThread;
    private static string rootPath = "";
    public Server()
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.Resolve("localhost").AddressList[0];
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 9501);
        //this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"].IPEndpoint);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        Trace.WriteLine("Server Working", "Information");
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }


    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start();
        Trace.WriteLine("Server TcpListener Started", "Information");
        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Trace.WriteLine("Server TcpListener New Client", "Information");
            // create a thread to handle the client
            //ParameterizedThreadStart HandleClientConn;
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Server TcpListener New Client Handle Thread", "Information");
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream nStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        Image img = Image.FromStream(nStream);
        Trace.WriteLine("Server TcpListener Image is received", "Information");
        string imageName = client.GetHashCode() + ".jpg";
        string imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot") + @"\", @"approot\"+ imageName);
        img.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        rootPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");
        Dictionary<string, string> templates = GetTemplates();
        string sDataDir = String.Format("{0}StasmData\\", rootPath);
        StasmHelper stasm = new StasmHelper();
        Face retVal = stasm.GetHumanFace(imagePath, sDataDir, templates);

        File.Delete(imagePath);
    }
```

Comment: Almost every significantly large app has threads. you could paste any of these and claim it as an answer... Except it doesn't answer this specific question. In the simplest case, an example of threaded code could be about 5 or so lines. Even that wouldn't answer the question though

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is not answer, but a sample. Another thing, this is my code.